# Perl modifying CSV files

Tags: perl, csv

I have a small section of code I'm trying to modify.
What I'm trying to do is have the filename inputted into the third column. At the moment I almost have it working, but I'd like to remove the ".csv"s from the end of each entry in the column. I'd also like to give the column the heading "filename".

[image: Table1]
[image: Table2]

I hope the difference between "table1" and "table2" shown above summarises quite well the modification which I'm trying to make here.

The code I'm currently using to create "table1" is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
open M,"<mapcodelist.txt" or die "mapcodelist.txt $!";
my %m;
while( <M> ){
    my($k,$v)=split;
    $v=~s/\./_/g;
    $m{$k}=$v;
}
close M;
chdir "C:/Users/Stephen/Desktop/Database_Design/" or die $!;
@ARGV=<*.csv>;
$^I=".bak";
while( <> ){
    chomp;
    $\=/^mass/?",filename$/": ",$ARGV$/";
    print;
}
for( <*.csv> ){
  my $r;
  ($r=$_) =~ s/\w+_(\w+)(?=\.csv)/$1_$m{$1}/;
  rename $_,$r or warn " rename $_,$r  $!";
}
```

Any advice with this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You now have enough reputation to add images. You could also just add example data as a code block.

Comment: Thanks simbabque, edited the post as you've suggested.

Comment: Please don't use regexes to modify the contents of your CSV lines.  Read each line with a module like Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS, modify the field that needs to be modified, and then rebuild and rewrite the CSV line.

Comment: And maybe try to give your variables a better name. `%m, $k, $v and $r` are not very good chosen.

Comment: Are you trying to alter a csv table, or rename files (names listed in the csv table) or both?

Comment: First of all, I did not write this script, I'm modifying an existing script which currently functions fine - which is why I've come to this forum for help as I'm not great with perl. Secondly, I'm trying to alter the csv table. The script also renames the files (which is fine) and I wish this to be kept as it is, I would simply like the code slightly altered to accomodate for the desired modification shown in the pictures. If this makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my ($prev_lc);

open my $fh, '<', shift or die;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ eol => "\n" }) or die;
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) { 
    if ( $csv->record_number == 1 ) { 
        $prev_lc = $row->[$#$row];
        $csv->print( \*STDOUT, [ @$row[0 .. $#$row - 1], 'Filename' ] );
        next;
    }

    $prev_lc =~ s/\.csv$//;
    $csv->print( \*STDOUT, [ @$row[0 .. $#$row - 1], $prev_lc ] );

    ## Previous last column.
    $prev_lc = $row->[$#$row];
}
```

It uses an auxiliar variable to add the missing header and process each whole data line at the same time. I simply use a regular expression to remove the extension.

With following dummy test data (`infile`) and assuming that last line doesn't have a file name because of the header:

```
mass,intensity,20130730_p12_A2.csv
2349.345,56.23423,20130730_p12_A2.csv
744.2884,5.01
```

Run the script like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

That yields:

```
mass,intensity,Filename
2349.345,56.23423,20130730_p12_A2
744.2884,20130730_p12_A2
```

Perhaps it's not perfect based in particular data that you didn't show, and I didn't take into account all that code that you posted where you handle many files. But you can see that it works in the way you asked it and it's left as work for you to adapt it to your needs, if neccesary.